# Handling POST requests within Spring

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am currently writing a spring application that utilizes JPA. However, I am confused on how to handle POST requests. I have a class Clothing that has a Brand variable:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLOTHING")
public class Clothing {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String imageURL;
    private String productURL;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<MedianGroup> groups;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Brand brand;


    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "like_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Like> likes;


    private ClothType type;

    private Gender gender;

    protected Clothing() {}
    public Clothing(String name, String imageURL, String productURL, Brand brand, ClothType type, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.productURL = productURL;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BRAND")
public class Brand {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String URL;
```

The post request handling creating a new clothing item is:

```
@PostMapping("/clothing")
    ResponseEntity<?> newItem(@RequestBody Clothing newItem) {
        System.out.println(assembler.toModel(newItem));
        EntityModel<Clothing> entityModel = assembler.toModel(repository.save(newItem));

        return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()).body(entityModel);
    }
```

I am hoping to find a method of using a JSON string as the request body and having the brand stored within the variable. Is there a way to do this? Would I be better off parsing the JSON string myself?

Answer (score 0):

Better use DTO, refer here https://www.javaguides.net/2021/02/spring-boot-dto-example-entity-to-dto.html. After reading the data, create two entity objects - read data from the DTO and assign the reference. Then do save call to do the association. Refer https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-one-mapping-example/